# Add IP Address to Amazon Web Services (AWS) PEM Key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ip, ip-address, pem

I have a website hosted using AWS and I can log in at the office but when I get home, it doesn't let me using the same credentials. How can I add my home's IP address to the account? I'm not sure if I have to whitelist it from somewhere in the AWS admin panel or add it to my PEM key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about logging on to AWS EC2 instance using SSH credentials using the same key pair that you used while on Office Network, I assume that you have created restricted inbound access to your instance. If this is the issue, to correct this, go to 'Security Group' in the AWS Management console and modify the IP part.

If you want to access your AWS instance from anywhere, create an entry in inbound section in the following manner:

Type Protocol Port Range Source:-
SSH    TCP    22    0.0.0.0/0

If you want access only from a selected list of ips, add those ips in the 'Range Source'.

Try to SSH again after making those changes and you should be able to access it from 'home network' as well as 'office network'.

Comment: So in the Linux console using PuTTY, I have to enter, for example, TCP 22 123.456.789.012/0 and that will whitelist my IP so I can access my instance of the AWS EC2?

Comment: No @RickHelston.  The restriction on the security group is in the Amazon AWS Management Console. http://aws.amazon.com/  Once logged in.  Go to EC2 and then look at your Security Groups